# Route traffic from one VPN to a second VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I have set up an OpenVPN server on my windows 7 64-bit PC.  I also have a subscription to a VPN service.  My aim is to be able to connect my android phone to the VPN server on my PC, and then route all traffic through the VPN service.  I have a NetGear WPN824 router.

I can get it working if I my phone is on my local network.  Then I can connect my phone to the VPN server using the local IP address of my PC.  In Network Connection in the control panel, I share the connection used by the VPN service with the connection used by the VPN server.  Then when I browse the internet on my phone, all traffic goes through the VPN service.  Very nice.

But if my phone is outside my local network, so I have to connect my phone to the local VPN using my PC's external IP address, then this method doesn't work.  If I connect my PC to the VPN service and then try to connect my phone to my own VPN, it just doesn't connect (the initial TLS handshake times out).  If I connect my phone to the local VPN first, then this connection is lost as soon as I connect my PC to the VPN service.

Does anybody know how I can get this working?

Comment: Once your server connects as a client to the VPN Service provider you can no longer connect to your own server unless you have policy based routing. Ask about policy based routing on windows.